# How to open activity from bottom navigation view with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I have a bottom navigation view. I would like to open an activity, not a fragment when clicking on one of the items. This is my code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navController = findNavController(navigation_fragment.id)
        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        userId = intent.getStringExtra("user_id")

        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.navigation_graph_take_photo -> {
                    cameraCheckPermission()
                }
            }
            true
        }
    }
```

While trying to figure out how to solve this problem, I realized that when the bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener method is executed, it nullifies the bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController) method.

But I could not figure out how to make it so that when you click on the rest of the navigation menu items, everything works like without my changes

Answer (score 0):

```
Using the below method open activity on the bottom navigation menu item and click-

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.getItemId()) {
            R.id.navigation_home -> {
                val obj_a= Intent(ActivityA@this, ActivityB::class.java)
                startActivity(obj_a)
                return true
            }
            R.id.navigation_bills -> {
                val obj_b= Intent(ActivityA@this, ActivityC::class.java)
                startActivity(obj_b)
                return true
            }
            R.id.navigation_scan -> {
                val obj_c = Intent(ActivityA@this, ActivityD::class.java)
                startActivity(obj_c)
                return true
            }
          
        }
        return false
    }
```